# Viagra website spam mail

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

My email yahoo account is picking random people from my email address book and sending them a link to a website to a site for Viagra pills and other pills that treat the same thing. I'm getting emails back from friends some amused by it and some are upset! How can I stop my yahoo account to stop sending these emails to people? It's pretty embarrassing!!!!

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you should do is change the password on your account.

The second thing you should do is run a check on your PC to see if there are any viruses or trojans installed. Once you've done that and cleaned your PC you should be in a better position.

It could be that someone is just forging (or spoofing) the e-mails using your address as the sender - but given that it appears to be targeted at people in your address book that is less likely, but not impossible. If that's the case then there's nothing you can do to stop the e-mails. All you'll be able to do is limit the damage by apologising to those who are upset.

Comment: If you changed the password *before* running the virus scan, and any viruses were found, then you should change it again.  Otherwise the virus may have captured and sent off the new password.

Comment: @mark4o - good point.